# Simple question on graphical representation of minmax decision rule

Tags: bayesian, decision-theory, minimax

In the picture below, I cannot understand why the minmax decision rule is on the line $R_1=R_2$.

$R_i=R(\theta_i,d)$, where $\theta_i$ is the parameter and $d$ is the decision rule. $S$ is the risk set. The thickened black line is the set of admissible decision rules; the points (black dots) on set $S$ are non-randomised decision rules.

[image]

Source: [Essentials of Statistical Inference](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/essentials-of-statistical-inference/7CDE4B08DD68DE7EE0B00F778FC29CCD) by Young, Smith.

Comment: The minimax solution does not have to lie along the line of equal risk unless the line of admissible procedures is concave.  You might want to sketch some of the contours of maximal risk on this plot: that is, draw contours of the function $f(R_1,R_2)=\max(R_1,R_2)$. Where in $S$ is the lowest contour going to be?

Comment: @whuber I'm don't think they give me a way to compare different risks. This example was taken from the following book in page 12. 

http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/mahdy/stat%20cources/Cambridge%20University%20Press%20-%20Essentials%20of%20statistical%20inference.pdf

Comment: I don't understand that comment.  If the coordinate axes in this image aren't risks, then what do you take them to be?

Comment: @whubber Please disregard my last comment. I now understand that the lowest contour is going to be on the line, at the cross. Many Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

This warrants delving into an elaboration in a general setup:

$\delta_0$ is minimax if

$$\sup_{\theta\in\Theta} R(\theta, \delta_0) = \inf_{\delta\in D^\ast}\sup_{\theta\in\Theta}R(\theta, \delta).\tag 1\label 1 $$

Let $\Theta := \{\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_k\} ;$ let $S\subset \mathbb R^k.$ So,  each component of a point $\langle y_i\rangle_{i=1}^k\in S$ would correspond to $y_i = R(\theta_i, \delta) $ for some $\delta\in D^\ast.$

Assume $S$ does have its boundary points.

Define for $c\in \mathbb R,~Q_c:= \{\mathbf y: y_i\leq c\};$ all $\delta$'s corresponding to $S\cap Q_c$ are equivalent in the sense that $\max_i R(\theta, \delta) = c.$

The minimax risk is the infimum of such $c$'s, say, $c_0.$ Then the minimax rules would be associated with $S\cap Q_{c_0}.$ The diagonal $y_1 = \cdots=y_k$ is not special; minimax point might or might not lie on it:

$\bullet$ Minimax point on diagonal line:

[image]

Notice the minimax risk $c_0$ and the corresponding decision rule $\delta_0$'s minimax point is a boundary point of $S$ and lies on the diagonal line.

$\bullet$ Minimax points not on diagonal line:

[image]

Notice the minimax points are not lying on the diagonal line. There is nothing special about this line.

---

### Reference/Figure Source:

$\rm [I]$ Mathematical Statistics: A Decision theoretic Approach, *Thomas S. Ferguson,* Academic Press, $1967,$ sec. $1.7,$ pp. $38-39.$